# can't set path of texlive on ubuntu

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, linux, document-configuration

I installed a full texlive by `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`  
then i added the fallowing code to ~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc ~/.profile

```
export PATH=/usr/share/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
enter code here export MANPATH=/usr/share/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/share/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
```

the problem i didn't get  the features and tools ..such as families of fonts,typing in different language..etc.

**Info may help**

1- I use vim for typing.

2- command `texconfig conf -sys`

```
    =========================== version information ==========================
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2019

==================== binaries found by searching $PATH ===================
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/share/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:
kpsewhich: /usr/bin/kpsewhich
updmap: /usr/bin/updmap
fmtutil: /usr/bin/fmtutil
texconfig: /usr/bin/texconfig
tex: /usr/bin/tex
pdftex: /usr/bin/pdftex
mktexpk: /usr/bin/mktexpk
dvips: /usr/bin/dvips
dvipdfmx: /usr/bin/dvipdfmx

=========================== active config files ==========================
/usr/bin/texconfig: 272: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texconfig/tcfmgr: not found
/usr/bin/texconfig: 272: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texconfig/tcfmgr: not found
/usr/bin/texconfig: 272: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texconfig/tcfmgr: not found
/usr/bin/texconfig: 272: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texconfig/tcfmgr: not found
/usr/bin/texconfig: 272: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texconfig/tcfmgr: not found
/usr/bin/texconfig: 272: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texconfig/tcfmgr: not found
/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
config.ps: not found
fmtutil.cnf: not found
mktex.cnf: not found
pdftexconfig.tex: not found
updmap.cfg: not found
XDvi: not found
```

cont.

```
  ============================= font map files =============================
        psfonts.map: /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts.map
        pdftex.map: /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
        ps2pk.map: /var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map
        
        =========================== kpathsea variables ===========================
        TEXMFMAIN=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
        TEXMFDIST=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
        TEXMFLOCAL=/usr/local/share/texmf
        TEXMFSYSVAR=/var/lib/texmf
        TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/etc/texmf
        TEXMFVAR=/home/mohammed/.texlive2019/texmf-var
        TEXMFCONFIG=/home/mohammed/.texlive2019/texmf-config
        TEXMFHOME=/home/mohammed/texmf
        VARTEXFONTS=/tmp/texfonts
```

Comment: You should not have to set the path apt will handle this for you (adding links in /usr/bin most likely)

Comment: Have you been trying to install two different LaTeX installations? Apt which presumably gives you TL 2019 on that system, and upsteam hence you refering to `texlive/2022` in those PATHs. Please explain **exactly** what you did.

Comment: You should not set path at all but you have set `PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/share/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:`  ie added the non-standard locatios _after_ `/usr/bin` so they do nothing, the latex in `/usr/bin` will always be found as that is first

Comment: If you are same user as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/663548/1090 you could have your accounts merged

Comment: @David Carlisle so why l can't use the installed packages of fonts and typing in different language(arabic) and even can't change the font size of text like when i change the font in `\documentclass[32pt]{article}` no thing change!.

Comment: you presumably have an error, if you asked a question about _that_ and showed a small complete example and the log that you get, someone would be able to answer.

Comment: `article` does not have a `32pt` option so naturally that will just generate an unused option warning. Re-installing a tex system will not change that